# Datatables and Using Filters

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and want to filter by group with toggle buttons.

Currently, my table shows tools that belong to the current user, but I want them to be able to search other groups' tools as well.

For example. User 1 belongs to Group 1. The table default shows all Group 1 tools. But when they click "Group 2", I want the table to update to show all group 2 tools.

Currently, this works with POST parameters:

```
  def my_search
    if params[:search][:value].present?
      records = Tool.full_text_search(params[:search][:value])
    elsif params[:group]
      records = Tool.where(group: params[:group])
    else
      records = Tool.where(group: current_user.group)
    end
  end
```

This is the jQuery that works with my rails function:

```
var toolTable = $('#tools-table').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    'url':'/tools.json',
    'data': {
      group: function () {
        return group;
      }
    }
  },
  "columns": [
    {data: '0'},
    {data: '1'},
    {data: '2'},
    {data: '3'},
    {data: '4'},
    {data: '5'}
  ],
  'columnDefs': [{
    'orderable': false,
    'targets': ['nosort']
  }],
  // autoWidth: false,
  // pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to add additional parameter to be sent to the server and that would be your group ID.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/test/0",
        "data": function(d){            
            d.form_group = $('#example-group').val();
        }
    }
});

// Handle filter change event
$('#example-group').on('change', function(){
    // Reload table data from Ajax data source
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
});
```

You need to handle this parameter (`form_group` in my example) on the server and return corresponding data.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcb3dL5a/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I'm using a toggle toolbar, like these: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html...But I've tried to use this example, and it seems like my data structure doesn't match yours. Will the datatable request each time there is a change?

Comment: @KevinBrown, yes `ajax.reload()` will force DataTables to send the request. Remember that you have to use `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` event instead of `change` (see [events](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html)). Also `$('#example-group').val()` would need to be replaced with appropriate method to retrieve a value of the switch.

Comment: So, I'm close. If I manually set `"data":"group_name"`, I get a filtered response. But when I set the function, no params are passed. I will update my code tomorrow.

Comment: Great! Had to fiddle, but you were a big help. THANK YOU!